# Can I build LLVM without having Python interpreter?

Tags: build, cmake, llvm

When building LLVM cmake configuration fails when it cannot find a Python interpreter. As I understand, Python is needed to run LLVM tests. I'm not interested in testing LLVM, tests are explicitly disabled in my configuration. Is it possible to force cmake not to require Python in this case?

Comment: I remember LLVM used Python to generate library dependencies files, so there was no way to build without Python. And i doubt this has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Building LLVM without Python is not possible at the moment. LLVM configuration uses [llvm-build](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/tree/master/utils/llvm-build) Python script to generate some additional files.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to pass `LLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=NO` to a `cmake` command:

```
LLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS:BOOL
    Generate build targets for the LLVM unit tests. Defaults to ON. You can use this option to disable the generation of build targets for the LLVM unit tests.
```

See LLVM docs: [LLVM-specific variables](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#llvm-specific-variables).

Comment: Then, obviously, I would look for a place where the Python gets required in LLVM's CMakeLists files and see if it depends on some flag that might be turned off. But you have probably been there as well. Very dirty hack could be to create your dummy "python" bash script - and point LLVM to it so that it doesn't block you.